# Как записать в переменную double из TextBox отрицательное число?

Tags: c#, winforms

Такая вот проблема, если ввожу в TextBox сразу цифры, все нормально, а если начинаю с минуса - отладка обрывается.
a2 объявлена ранее в коде как переменная double. Что можно сделать?

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }
```

Comment: текст ошибки нужен

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Comment: Вместо метода `Parse()` надо использовать `TryParse()`

Comment: В смысле как? Он требует два аргумента, что передать вторым?

Comment: Это естественно: `-` не является числом. Поэтому, если введён только минус, то ошибка парсинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out a2);
```

Comment: Неа, **Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'**

Comment: @Yulia Ага. Вы неправильно скопировали мой код. У меня нет никакого присваивания `a2 = ...;`

Comment: а, точно, спасибо